# Java program keeps exiting program prematurely

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to build a simple automaton for my Automata class. I am using Java and I cannot figure out for the life of me why my program keeps exiting prematurely. I've tried debugging it, having print statements everywhere to figure out where it's stopping, and although I know where it stops, I do not see anything that would make the program stop working. The stoppage happens on line 27 (Right where I SOP "Enter a string of digits...".
Knowing me it's probably something simple, but I cannot figure this one out.

```
import java.util.*;
public class hw1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please indicate the number of states");
    int numState = input.nextInt();
    int[] state = new int[numState];
    boolean[] accept = new boolean[numState];
    for (int i = 0; i < numState; i++) {
        System.out.println("Is the state q" + (i + 1) + " a final state? (Answer 1 for yes; 0 for no)");
        int finalState = input.nextInt();
        if (finalState == 1)
            accept[i] = true;
    } // for
    System.out.println("Enter the number of symbols s: ");
    int numSym = input.nextInt();

    int[][] next = new int[numState][numSym];
    for (int i = 0; i < numState; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numSym; j++) {
            System.out.println("What is the number for the next state for q" + i + " when it gets symbol " + j);
            next[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }//nested for
    }//for

    String digits = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a string of digits (0-9) without spaces to test:");

    int[] digitArray = new int[digits.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
        digitArray[i] = digits.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(digitArray[i] + " ,");
    }
    System.out.println("end of program");
}// main;

}// class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter a string of digits (0-9) without spaces to test:");
String digits = input.nextLine();
```

This will get and ignore the newline character left in the stream after call to `nextInt()`

Comment: I have placed the Print statement after the nextLine statement and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @OmarKhalik - Check my *updated* answer. I said *add new nextLine()` . :)